# Photoshop CS6 Colour display issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've had this issue with Photoshop where some dark blues are displayed in black on Photoshop if I'm in RGB mode and selecting dedicated graphics in the performance preferences. If I don't select dedicated graphics or change to CMYK the issue gets fixed although I would like to be able to work in RGB mode and have the dedicated graphics on. What can I do?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I recently brought a new computer with Windows 8. I upgraded to Photoshop CS6 64-bit, and ever since I have had display issues. I get flashes and the Photoshop workspace turns to black when I am working. Colors display as if they were out of gamut or posterized as you describe (appearing as black over areas of the image). One thing I did find out was that by upgrading to the latest beta driver for Photoshop that the flashing and blacking of the workspace improves, though the problem persists. You might want to try this.

Comment: probably yes, but did you update your video cards's drivers to the most recent versions?

Comment: I also have similar issue, on my Windows 7. Some cyan-like colors will be displayed as black. When I drag the window of the photo around, strange enough, the cyan can be displayed normally while dragging! What problem is it likely to be??

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read [the Q&A in this link](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/when_life_open_in_photoshop_black_squared_patches_appear) I just found. From that page:

> Looks like a problem with your display calibration.  It could be the
>   display profile, or it could be a bug in your video card driver (the
>   shaders used to perform color correction).
>
> Try setting the Photoshop GPU mode to "Basic", then relaunching
>   Photoshop.  If that solves it, then the cause was the shaders (and a
>   bug in the driver).  If that doesn't solve it, then the problem is
>   most likely your display profile.

Comment: I do recommend this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the `30 bit display` checkbox.

My cyan color looks normal again without blacky color, without sacrificing advanced GPU mode.